# Node.JS Mongoose: .find() is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm pulling my hair out...this function worked perfectly until last night...I didn't make any changes to the underlying code and it seems to have just randomly quit working. Code below:

```
var KeyWord = require('./word');      

console.log(KeyWord);                  // returns {}

KeyWord.find().select('_id').exec(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error getting word");
        } else {
          console.log("Found");
    }
  });
```

Below is the KeyWord object

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Account = require('./account');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var KeyWordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  chinese: String,
  english: [String],
  pinyin: [String],
  tone: Number,
  count: Number
});



var KeyWord = mongoose.model('KeyWord', KeyWordSchema);

module.exports = KeyWord;
```

The error I get back is:

```
KeyWord.find().select('_id').exec(function(err, result) {
        ^
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I ran the top bit of code in my index.js and it worked, printing "Found". The word.js file and the file that I am running the function in are in the same folder.

Comment: And, all of this code is in the same .js file? If not, how are you getting `KeyWord` to the first snippet?

Comment: No it's not the same file. I'm importing keyword (sorry forgot to include that) - the import works. I have printed mongoose and KeyWord and neither is listed as undefined. I also tried other model functions like save and findOne and both of them were listed as undefined as well.

Comment: To me it sounds like `KeyWord` isn't a mongoose model in your first snippet, which would suggest it's being imported or exported improperly. It looks like you're exporting it properly, which leaves the import step that you haven't included.

Comment: (Deleted my non-relevant comments)   @ChrisWood this sounds like a circular reference issue.  Does your model require the same file you are trying to import the model into or some sort of weird love triangle of files?

Comment: Just run it under the debugger and see what `KeyWord` actually is, as it doesn't appear to be a Mongoose model.

Comment: Thank all of you for the help, @JamesLeClair got it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a circular reference.  Does your model import the same file that you are trying to import back into it?

When you inspect KeyWord in the file you are attempting to run .find().. does KeyWord return an empty object `{}` ?

If I'm right, when you do this:

```
var KeyWord = require('/path/to/model/file')
console.log(KeyWord)
```

output should show `{}` and not something like `[object Object]`

Comment: It does give me a `{}`! I import the same file in both of them, and that file requires the two files listed above...maybe that's doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is because **KeyWord** is undefined. First you have to create the **KeyWord** variable before calling the `KeyWord.find().select('_id')`

change the code like this:

```
var KeyWord = require('./models/KeyWord');//Your path to KeyWord schema file here

KeyWord.find().select('_id').exec(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error getting word");
    } else {
      console.log("Found");
    }
});
```

Comment: If `KeyWord` was undefined, the error message would be very different. `ReferenceError: KeyWord is not defined`